# Rasa-X takes too long to install

Tags: python, rasa, rasa-x

```
pipenv install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

using the pipenv library and `Python 3.7.6` with `pyenv` and its taken more than 5 hours...

During that time, it's just doing the following:

[image]

I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work...

Versions:

`pip -> 20.2`

`pipenv -> version 2021.11.23`

`pyhton -> 3.7.6`

Any suggestions ? Something is clearly wrong...

Comment: What is it doing during those 5 hours?

Comment: I updated the question @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

The latest version of pip 21.3 solved the problem for me.

Comment: Yeah @Sorcerer - I have done that and dependency resolving has made it much quicker when updating the `pip`, although I now have another issue -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70727477/rasa-3-0-4-not-installing-due-to-dependency-issues

Comment: Consider using a different python version, maybe 3.8