# rasa 3.0.4 not installing due to dependency issues

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, pipenv, rasa

I am trying to install the rasa==3.0.4 version, but it fails to do so with error in the:

- `tensorflow`
- `tensorflow-addons`

dependencies... giving the following errors:

[image]

I have tried to individually install each depencendy, for example: `tensorflow-addons==0.15.0` but I get the same errors... how can I make it work ?

Replicate this issue with the following dev `environment`:

- `OS` -> Windows 10
- `pipenv` : 2021.11.23
- `python --version` -> 3.7.6
- `python bitness` -> 64bit
- `pip --version` -> 21.3.1
- `rasa (trying to install 3.0.4)`

Comment: OS? `python --version` ? `pip --version` ? Python bitness (32 or 64): `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"` ?

Comment: Updated question @phd

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of errors. Copy paste them into your question instead

Comment: tensorflow addons should be available for python 3.7-3.9. Can you confirm that the python version you wrote in your question is form the python that the pip belongs to? Can you try `python -m pip install tensorflow-addons==0.15.0`?